# How to vary the tone of an image dynamically using only css?

Tags: css

I have an image file and I want to show it in different tones with respect to different events. Say for on a click event on a button,I need to pass a color code and the tone of the image must be of that color. How can I do this,preferably only css?

Comment: you could make a png with transparence and change the background color. or change opacity of image and change the backround color of wrapping tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the colour blend feature available in css3. A sample would be:

```
.blend {
  background-image:url(blend-mode-mult.jpg);
  width:450px;
  height:450px;
  background-color: #f79e9e;/*pass your color variable here*/
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this? I used `#f6ff00` for this test, but you could of course use whatever. You can also change the `.active` class's opacity value.

```js
$('.frame').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).find('.color-block').addClass('active').css('background-color', '#f6ff00');
}).mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).find('.color-block').removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.frame{
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  position:relative;
}
.frame img{
   width: 100%; 
   height: 100%;
}
.frame .color-block{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  opacity:0;
}
.frame .color-block.active{
  opacity: 0.3;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="frame">
<div class="color-block"></div>
<img src="http://photos2.appleinsidercdn.com/13.01.31-Newell.jpg">
</div>
```